# Java & Bytebuddy : How to get MethodDelegation to work properly

Tags: java, delegation, byte-buddy, intercept

I have the following code

```
package io.xxx.intercepter;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodDelegation;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.AllArguments;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Empty;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.Origin;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.RuntimeType;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.SuperMethod;
import net.bytebuddy.implementation.bind.annotation.This;
import net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers;

public class Proxy {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    new ByteBuddy()
    .subclass(Person.class)
    .method(ElementMatchers.any())
    .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(Interceptor.class))
    .make()
    .load(Person.class.getClassLoader())
    .getLoaded()
    .getDeclaredConstructor()
    .newInstance()
    .getJob("egnineer");
  }
  
  public class Person {
    
    private String work = "coding";
    
    public Person() {}
    
    public String getJob(String job) {
      
      this.work = job;
      
      System.out.println("I'm the Person " + work);
      
      return work;
    }
  }

 public class Interceptor {
  
    @RuntimeType
    public static Object intercept(
        @This Object self, 
        @Origin Method method,
        @AllArguments Object[] args,
        @SuperMethod(nullIfImpossible = true) Method superMethod,
        @Empty Object defaultValue) throws Throwable {
  
      if(superMethod == null)
        return defaultValue;
      
      System.out.println("I'm the proxy --> " + method.getName());
 
      Object object = superMethod.invoke(self, args);
  
      return object;

    }
  }
}
```

**Goal :** To intercept the `person.getJob(String)` method

**Problem :**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: io.xxx.intercepter.Proxy$Person$ByteBuddy$LI9kwh7B.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3585)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2754)
    at io.xxx.intercepter.Proxy.main(Proxy.java:25)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't you want to intercept to Interceptor.class rather then Proxy.class?

I assume it's as simple as that.

Comment: Apologies, that was a typo. I corrected the example so that It is intercepting the 'Interceptor.class'.  The issue still remains

Comment: Ah, I see. You import advice annotations when you want to use bind annotations.

Comment: Ah I think I discovered a bug/feature? I noticed the the above example that Byte buddy cannot discover the default constructor of the inner "Person" class unless it can be instantiated without its parent (or simply marked static)

Comment: A non static inner class is nested and has no default constructor as it takes its outer instance as an implicit parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the help & good work with ByteBuddy!